# Illegal unit of measure, even though i use cm?

Tags: measure

I keep getting this error on multiple lines, even though I have inserted a unit of measure? This line:

```
\includegraphics[width=15cm\textwidth]{Billeder/brandtabel.png}
```

Why does it give me this error even though I use cm? if I change it to inch it still gives the same error.

Comment: `15cm\textwidth` is "15cm * `\textwidth`" or in other words 15cm times the width of the text area: You could argue that this has too many units (the  `\textwidth` also comes with a unit). Try something like `\includegraphics[width=1\textwidth]{Billeder/brandtabel.png}` or `\includegraphics[width=15cm]{Billeder/brandtabel.png}` instead.

Comment: Welcome! Your `width=15cm` is followed by `\textwidth`, that isn't correct. You should either use `width=15cm` or `width=15\textwidth` (the latter seems unreasonable big).

Comment: Perfect, thank you!! Now i understand it.

Answer (score 2):

Both 15cm and \textwidth are lengths, so you can't put them together as multiplying them doesn't make sense as a length. To get a fraction of the textwidth you'd use `width=0.5\textwidth` or if you wanted a length in cm use `width=15cm`